# SDDM was broken after system update

Tags: linux, systemd, archlinux, kde-plasma

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE and SDDM for about 6 months. A few days ago I got a usual [system update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3De6.jpg). On next day, after reboot, system stuck at a black screen with `Starting version 243.0-1-arch`. Then I press `Ctrl+Alt+F2` and inter `tty` terminal, logged in and `$startx` - GUI was loaded. Next time when I try to start sddm manually in tty terminal with `$ systemctl start sddm` nothing happened. That's what  **journalctl -b -1 | grep sddm** says about it:

```
сен 23 02:48:55 jenkins audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=sddm comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
сен 23 02:48:55 jenkins sddm[630]: Initializing...
сен 23 02:48:55 jenkins sddm[630]: Starting...
сен 23 02:48:55 jenkins sddm[630]: Logind interface found
сен 23 03:00:03 jenkins sddm[630]: Signal received: SIGTERM
сен 23 03:00:03 jenkins systemd[1]: sddm.service: Succeeded.
сен 23 03:00:03 jenkins audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=sddm comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
сен 23 03:00:03 jenkins kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1569196803.849:47): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=sddm comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

And another listing **systemctl status sddm**:

```
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disab>
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-09-23 10:30:06 MSK; 6h ago
     Docs: man:sddm(1)
           man:sddm.conf(5)
 Main PID: 427 (sddm)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 12.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
           └─427 /usr/bin/sddm

сен 23 10:30:06 jenkins systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
сен 23 10:30:06 jenkins sddm[427]: Initializing...
сен 23 10:30:06 jenkins sddm[427]: Starting...
сен 23 10:30:06 jenkins sddm[427]: Logind interface found
```

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **dritter** for your answer, unfortunately I can't verify its correctness because I found another solution, even two (I checked both options - all are working). So, first solution is to **downgrade Linux-lts** core (in my case from 4.19.73-1 to 4.19.72-1 or lower). Another solution (that I settled on) is to **install nvidia-dkms** drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a race condition. SDDM starts, while the video driver is not ready yet.

A proper solution is to add your graphics driver to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to the `MODULES` key. Then you have to rebuild the ramdisk that loads on startup: `mkinitcpio -p linux`. After that, reboot.

The graphic driver to add depends on your hardware. For me it is (as I use an Intel card), it is `i915`. Type `lsmod` to get a list of all loaded kernel modules.